# Can I "Wipe data/Factory reset" a phone that doesn't even boot via USB?

Tags: security, unbricking

I have a Razr HD (XT925 GSM) which suddenly shut down and can't be turned back on (pressing or long pressing the power button does nothing, nor does connecting it to the wall).

I have a lot of sensible stuff in the phone. I'd like to wipe it before taking it to the repair service but I don't know if it is possible at all. The phone doesn't even show up when connected to the USB port. Is there a way to wipe the on board flash in these conditions?

Knowing that the answer is most probably not, how would you approach the issue? Should I just throw away the phone?

Thanks!

ps: some context. The phone's screen cracked some time ago. For a few months nothing happened. About a month about the phone started rebooting itself about 10 times a day, with no discernible pattern. It just shut down, apparently for good; I had last checked the notifications a few minutes before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen such an issue before, but it was a samsung device.
I do not have a cookbook solution for you, just some points to check:

Is the powerbutton still working? Did you have issues with buttons before? On the samsung we had to create a special plug from a cable and a 3k resistor. This brings the samsung phones directly to download-mode where you can flash and or reboot.

Is your battery still ok? Can you replace it (quickly exchange with a friend) or is this not possible with your phone type?

Is your charger ok? And the cable? Try another one and leave it on for a while, a dead battery needs a bit of time and very slow charge, before it can go back to normal charging.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! While I was looking for a solution like the download-mode cable, I think that economically the best way forward will be to purchase a new phone.